# Assigning a "line" number to groups of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping, sql-server-2016

I have some data that looks like the following (this is just a small subset):

```
ID              Desc          Proj_Id     Year    Master_Line_Num
1          "Development"       "C102"     2017     ?Should be 1?
2          "Development"       "C102"     2018     ?Should be 2?
3          "Development"       "C102"     2019     ?Should be 3?
4          "Dev"               "B123"     2017     ?Should be 1?
5          "Dev"               "B123"     2018     ?Should be 2?
6          "Dev"               "B123"     2019     ?Should be 3?
```

I am having some trouble writing the SQL for assigning the Master_Line_Num. Basically, the "Desc" and "Proj_ID" will be in the table having rows for specific years. I'd like to assign the master_line_num in order of the year for that desc/proj. Is that possible? The result that I desire is the values on the column on the far right (1,2,3,1,2,3)

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Show us the expected result as well. And also your current query attempt. (BTW, SQL-2016 is the current ANSI SQL standard.)

Comment: What happens if a year is missing for a production/desc combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
row_number() over (partition by [DESC], proj_id order by [year])
```

I was going to fix Joel's answer but there are too many issues:

- `partition by` goes before `order by`
- There is no need to repeat the keys in the `partition by` and `order by` clauses.

If you want to handle missing years, so 2017 is always 1, and 2019 is always 3 even if 2018 is missing, you can use arithmetic and window functions:

```
select (1 + year - min(year) over ())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
row_number() over (order by [DESC], Proj_ID, Year partition by [DESC], proj_id)
```

Comment: Is this standard syntax?  I've never seen it before.

Comment: It's for Sql Server 2012 and later, but windowing functions like this are supported since 2012 by every major DB but MySql.

Comment: This worked!! Thank you a ton!! I knew that was the route I'd have to take just could not figure out the syntax.

Comment: I think it should be `ORDER BY YEAR`. `ORDER BY Desc` will work based on the sample data posted but that's coincidental.

Comment: You can use `year` with`order by` alone (due to using `desc, proj_id` in `partition by`